# Getting sqlx MapScan to return strings

Tags: postgresql, go

The sqlx package has a MapScan function that's quite handy in that it returns a row as a map (map[string]interface{}) but all string columns come out as runes (if I'm not mistaken). Is there a way to have it just return as strings instead?

sqlx - github.com/jmoiron/sqlx

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue when dealing with sql in go.  Some googling lead me to the go [driver](https://godoc.org/database/sql/driver#Value) docs.  Here is what they have for a Value type returned from a query.

> Value is a value that drivers must be able to handle. It is either nil or an instance of one of these types:
>
> - int64
> - float64
> - bool
> - []byte
> - string  [*] everywhere except from Rows.Next.
> - time.Time

Strings are returned as byte slices (when you attempt to encode []bytes into json it base64s it).  I have not found a way within the framework of sqlx or sql/db to return strings instead of []byte slices, but did come up with a quick and dirty conversion for slices in a map.  There is limited type checking, but it is a good start.

```
func convertStrings(in map[string]interface{}) {
    for k, v := range in {
        t := reflect.TypeOf(v)
        if t != nil {
            switch t.Kind() {
            case reflect.Slice:
                in[k] = fmt.Sprintf("%s", v)

            default:
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```